# Line that best fits the points $p_1,\ldots,p_n$.

Tags: real-analysis, lagrange-multiplier

I'm trying to solve this problem: Let $p_j=(x_j,y_j)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ $(j=1,\ldots,n)$ with $p_i\neq p_j$ for $i\neq j$. Find the function of de form $f(x)=ax+b$ such that

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n} (f(x_j)-y_j)^2=\sum_{j=1}^{n}(ax_j+b-y_j)^2=F(a,b)$$

is a minimum.

We are trying the theme of Lagrange multipliers. I considered the function $F\colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ given by

$$F(l,m)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}(lx_j+m-y_j)^2$$

for which we want to find a minimum. However I don't know the function I can use like a constraint to apply Lagrange multipliers. Also I obtained the gradient of $F$ and equaling it to $0$ I found $m$ in terms of the points $(x_j,y_j)$ but to obtain $l$ I have a factor that accompanies $l$ and may be it could be 0 in some case and is not possible to divide by it. I don't know if equaling the gradient to (0,0) is the correct way to solve this. Could you give me sone suggestions for this problem? Which is the constraint  function in this case? Thanks.

Comment: Use the least squares method from Linear Algebra.

Comment: I saw that it is solved with least squares method, but the problem is planted in the theme of Lagrange multipliers. So I think that may be i can't use that. Could you please recommend me another idea?

Comment: I think that the construction using Lagrange multipliers is in this case essentially the same as the construction using least squares.

Answer (score 1):

Using gradient of $F$ :
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial a} = 2\sum_{j=1}^n x_j(ax_j+b-y_j)$$
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial b} = 2\sum_{j=1}^n (ax_j+b-y_j)$$
$\frac{\partial F}{\partial b}=0$ means
$$a\sum_j x_j + nb-\sum_jy_j=0\iff b=\bar y-a\bar x$$
where $\bar x=\frac1n\sum_j x_j$ is the mean value of the $x$ values$.

Now $\frac{\partial F}{\partial b}=0$ gives you
$$a\sum_j x_j^2+n\bar x\bar y-na\bar x^2-\sum_j x_jy_j=0 \iff a\left(\frac1n\sum x_j^2-\bar x^2\right) = \frac1n\sum_jx_jy_j-\bar x\bar y$$
so
$$a=\frac{{\rm Cov}(X,Y)}{{\rm Var}(X)}$$
as expected.

Comment: Thanks. I have a question. What can I say in the case Var$(X)$=0? In this part I can't divide by it. Also, is there a way to prove that indeed with this values of $a$ and $b$ we have a minimum for this function?

Comment: Var(x)=0 means x is constant, so your line is vertical...